# Private Pypi server vs Private Github repo

Tags: python, github, pip, pypi

I'm trying to understand the advantages of hosting your own Pypi server over pip installing from a private github repo.
If I can include github dependency links in the setup.py or requirement.txt, and github URLs support versioning.
The only point I can see so far is readability i.e.

```
pip install my_package==1.0.0
```

instead

```
pip install git+https://github.com/my_package@v1.0.0#egg=my_package-1.0.0
```

Comment: With pypi, packages are built elsewhere and bundled for the install which means it can handle more package types than pulling from github and calling its setup.py. Installing from git means cloning, you could also just install from a tar file or zip. If your package is installable from git then its fine to do it that way... assuming all users have git.

Answer (score 4):

In short, PyPI supports many features that installing from git does not. The features are too numerous to name them all, but a few include:

- Support for uploading & installing from compiled binaries (e.g. wheels, tar.gz, source, etc)
- Support for "yanking" releases
- Support for multiple formats, including source, eggs, wheels, and more.
- Resolving multiple versions of your package and its compatibility with the version, platform and architecture (e.g. Python 3.6.4 on windows_x86 vs python 3.7.1 on linux_x64) of Python for the client (e.g. automatically installs compatible versions of *your* package)
- Resolving the appropriate version of your package as a dependency for other projects
- Can be added as an (additional) index server when resolving from many servers
- Support for pre-releases
- Can be installed by clients without `git`